# Application of billiards

Tags: big-list, applications, billiards

Studying billiards is a difficult problem in general, even in pretty simple cases it has plenty of interesting properties.

I would like to understand what can be applications (mathematically or in concrete life or other sciences) of billiards. Are they used to model physical problems for instance?

I can only think of physics particles bumping into a compact box, is it relevant?

Comment: I do know that the reverse question, mathematically modeling billiards is no walk in the park.  Complications include striking a cue ball at some location *off center* to impart english and the drag caused by the inelastic collisions of either the cue ball to the object ball, or the object ball to a rail.  As an example, when elementary pocket billiards books discuss where to aim the cue ball, they don't consider the relationship between the speed of the cue ball and the drag when the cue ball hits the object ball.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for your comment. Maybe even in much simpler cases, with a single point ball and perfect rigid collisions, I would like to know if there are some applications

Comment: My **blind speculation**, which could easily be wrong, is **no**.  The scenario where math/science studies one area and then uses this study to facilitate progress in another area doesn't seem to apply to pocket billiards.  Why would math/science professors study this in the first place?  If there is an application, why has no one heard about it?  Finally, although your atomic collisions idea is plausible, it's hard to imagine physicists studying pocket billiards to help them collide atoms.  Can you *put english* on an atom to control its direction?

Comment: Also, absent the pocket billiard complexities of  english and drag/inelastic collisions, what would an atomic physicist gain by watching for example, the motion of billiard balls on an ice skating rink?

Comment: See the many answers at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/195739/12357

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely they are used to model physical problems. They are almost a go-to model for any first-pass-investigation of classical (and now in some cases quantum) phenomena. The first reason for their popularity is that one can do away with complicated evolution laws and instead alter dynamical behaviours by changing the shape of the table. And there is indeed a wealth of different behaviours to be observed, [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043928/parabolic-elliptic-and-hyperbolic-dynamical-systems) starring as the main actors in dynamical systems. The second reason is that despite simple evolution rules, they are not entirely trivial for the most part. It is not as though you can pick an arbitrary table geometry and produce detailed results about any old observable. This leaves plenty of room for theoretical physicists to focus on their physics, without the need to explain in-depth mathematical results which don't exist yet.

The opening chapter of Boltzmann's lectures on gas theory is a "mechanical analogy" based on hard spheres:

> The simplest such picture is one in which the molecules are completely elastic, negligibly deformable spheres, and the wall of the container is a completely smooth and elastic surface. However, when it is convenient we can assume a different law of force. Such a law, provided it is agreement with the general mechanical principles, will be no more and no less justified than the original assumption of elastic spheres.

In less particular circumstances, there is often an equivalent representation for [hard sphere models as regular billiards](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02634v1). In this direction is has to be said that statistical physics has [benefited](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06284) a great deal from billiard models.

No one is going to argue that perfectly elastic reflections or walls with infinite potential are real. But it is often easier to discover and develop new phenomena with pen, paper and computer than to conduct experiments. Once these phenomena can be established in real systems, the two realms (ideally) feed off each other. As for 1-1 applications (as opposed to models), I don't think so. Although it wouldn't surprise me if there were very accurate measurements; maybe optical wave guides or Knudsen environments. There are also a number of modifications which can be made to make things more 'realistic': external fields, non-specular reflections, time delayed reflections, ray splitting, finite sized (not necessarily spherical) billiard balls, ....